# ros2 Iron Ubunto 22.04 Could not import 'rosidl_typesupport_c' custom msg error ...ways to fix. not sure whats wrong

Tags: ros2, ubuntu, custom-message

I am not able to find out why I receive the ROS2 error ....

```
[rosidl_generator_py.import_type_support_impl.UnsupportedTypeSupport: Could not import 'rosidl_typesupport_c' for package 'tutorial_interfaces']
```

This shows up as a run time error.  The code compiles fine.

I have ROS2 publisher/subscriber nodes running on another computer.  I then took a working publisher to a new computer to only see it fail.

The old computer is running Ubunto 22.04 on a Raspberry Pi.
The new computer is running Ubunto 22.04 (Linux Mint) on Virtual Box/PC.

On the new computer, the identical source code fails with the above error.  There is a custom message in its own package that is the root cause of the error.  If I do not use the custom message, my code works fine.

I reduced both the custom message and publisher to minimal versions and still have the same problems.  I followed a tutorial to create a custom message and use it in a seperate python node.

The below code can be made to fail by changing the word String to Num in the publisher....

```py
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from std_msgs.msg import String

from tutorial_interfaces.msg import Num


class MinimalPublisher(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('minimal_publisher')
        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(String, 'topic', 10)
        timer_period = 0.5  # seconds
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
        self.i = 0

    def timer_callback(self):
        msg = String()
        msg.data = 'Hello World: %d' % self.i
        self.publisher_.publish(msg)
        self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "%s"' % msg.data)
        self.i += 1


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    minimal_publisher = MinimalPublisher()

    rclpy.spin(minimal_publisher)

    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    minimal_publisher.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`package.xml`

For the message

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>tutorial_interfaces</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="jeffrey@todo.todo">jeffrey</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <buildtool_depend>rosidl_default_generators</buildtool_depend>
  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(tutorial_interfaces)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(tutorial_interfaces
  "msg/Num.msg"
)

ament_package()
```

For my test node

`setup.py`

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

package_name = 'jemtstnode'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['test']),
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='jeffrey',
    maintainer_email='jeffrey@todo.todo',
    description='TODO: Package description',
    license='TODO: License declaration',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'jeffTstNode = jemtstnode.jefPub:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

`package.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>jemtstnode</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="jeffrey@todo.todo">jeffrey</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <depend>tutorial_interfaces</depend>
  <depend>rclpy</depend>
  <depend>std_msgs</depend>
  <depend>tutorial_interfaces</depend>

  <test_depend>ament_copyright</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_flake8</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_pep257</test_depend>
  <test_depend>python3-pytest</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
</package>


_________________________________
 
 Please advise what might be going on here and how I can best debug.  The tool `ros2 doctor --report` says that ros2 is working correctly.
```

Comment: https://github.com/ros2/examples/issues/303#issuecomment-1024891001 has a similar error, looks like several people solved it by deactivating conda (which was mixing in a different python version)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution and it exactly as Lucas (above in comment) referred me to.  When I deactivated conda, everything worked as expected.  I need to spend more time on my own learning about the interactions between conda and my ros2 build.  I realize it is probably a python conflict.  Of course, being very new doesn't help.  Anyways, if you ever have this issue, start looking at conda problems